# Calling smart contract function from frontend is not working

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, react, hardhat-deploy

I've created a twitter profile contract and a function called

```
contract Twitter {
    //Struct for user profile
    struct Profile {
        string name;
        string username;
        string bio;
        string location;
        string profilePic;
    }

//Struct for tweets
    struct Tweet {
        uint256 _id;
        string tweetImg;
        string tweetText;
        uint256 timeStamp;
        string profileImg;
        string name;
        string username;
        uint256 likes;
    }

    mapping(address => Profile) public profiles;
    mapping(address => Tweet[]) public tweets;
    Tweet[] public allTweets;
    uint256 public tweetCounter;

    function createProfile(
        string memory _name,
        string memory _username,
        string memory _bio,
        string memory _location,
        string memory _profilePic,
        string memory _coverPic
    ) public {
        require(
            bytes(profiles[msg.sender].username).length == 0,
            "User already exists."
        );
        Profile memory newProfile = Profile(
            _name,
            _username,
            _bio,
            _location,
            _profilePic,
            _coverPic
        );
        profiles[msg.sender] = newProfile;
    }

    mapping(address => Profile) public profiles;

    //Check profile exists
    function checkProfile(address _address) public view returns (bool) {
        if (bytes(profiles[_address].username).length > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And I've generated the contract address and abi by deploying the code using hardhat.

Then called the function form the frontend like this

```
  const checkProfileIsExist = async () => {
    try {
      const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);
      const signer = await provider.getSigner();
      const contract = new ethers.Contract(
        CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
        CONTRACT_ABI,
        signer
      );
      const response = await contract.checkProfile(account);
      console.log(response, "res");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error, "ERROR");
    }
  }

const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    try {
      if (disabled) return;
      const { coverPic, profilePic, name, username, location, bio } = data;
      const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);
      const signer = provider.getSigner();
      const contract = new ethers.Contract(
        CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
        CONTRACT_ABI,
        signer
        );
      const response = await contract.createProfile(
        name,
        username,
        bio,
        location,
        profilePic,
        coverPic
      );
      await response.wait();
      console.log(response, "response");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error, "ERROR");
    }
  };
```

When I run the code, The "checkProfileIsExist" function works since it's a get function. BUt the "onSubmit" function is not working. It throws the error,

> contract runner does not support sending transactions
> (operation="sendTransaction", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION,
> version=6.8.0)

This is my hardhat.config file,

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.19",
  networks: {
    sepolia: {
      url: `https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/${API_KEY}`,
      accounts: [
        `${PRIVATE_KEY}`,
      ],
    },
  },
};
```

I don't know why this error comes. No documentation is clear about it. Any help on this would be appreciated since I'm new to blockchain dev.

Comment: Strange one, I am also getting that kinda error. Maybe it's the version conflicts but idk.

Comment: by digging more i manage to found that `This Error indicates that a provided set of data cannot  be correctly interpretted.` so make sure `account` is defined or pass it manually in code first and see the result will work.

Comment: @Iftikharuddin I've made some changes in the question above. Could you please look at it ?

Comment: Are you sure you are on sepolia network? from config it seems you are on sepolia. Please double check that. After that reset your wallet also, sometime everything with code is fine, it's just cache issue. Delete artifacts, delete cash, reset wallet cache and re-try.

Answer (score 2):

So by digging a lot, I finally found the reason for the error. The issue is with the ethers version 6. I think this version of ethers is still unstable. That's why I couldn't able to find the cause since it's new version. The compatible version of ethers is version 5.7.2. When I downgraded the version, the issue got fixed.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `const signer = provider.getSigner();`, the function `getSigner` returns a promise, so if you add `await`, it will solve the issue.

The updated code will look like this:

```js
const signer = await provider.getSigner();
```

Adding `await` ensures that the signer is properly awaited, allowing you to work with it once the promise is resolved.